# Running into an infinite loop when using useEffect() in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, infinite-loop

I have recently begun using react native and I'm building this mobile application using Expo. I am using `useEffect()` to be able to call a function inside it. All I want is to wait for the reponse of the API to finish completely before I display the result (which in this case is the `connectionName` variable). I gave the `useEffect()` function `wallets`as a second parameter because I want the API fetched again whenever `wallets` changes, but I seem to be running in an infinite loop even though `wallets` hasn't changed. Any help is much appreciated.

```
export default function LinksScreen() {

       const [wallets, setWallets] = React.useState([]);
       const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
       const [connectionName, setConnectionName] = React.useState("loading...");

       React.useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
             fetchConnections();
          })();
       }, [wallets]);

       async function fetchConnections() {

          const res = await fetch('https://api.streetcred.id/custodian/v1/api/' + walletID + '/connections', {
             method: 'GET',
             headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
             },
          });
          res.json().then(res => setWallets(res)).then(setConnectionName(wallets[0].name))
       }

       return (
          <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
             <OptionButton
                icon="md-school"
                label={connectionName}
                onPress={() => WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://docs.expo.io')}
             />
          </ScrollView>
       );
    }
```

Comment: The useEffect hook will re-run every time a dependency in the array of dependencies changes. If the function in your hook changes the dependencies, it will loop forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect hook runs every time `wallets` changes, and it calls `fetchConnections`, which calls `setWallets`, which then triggers your useEffect hook because it changed `wallets`, and so on...

Pass an empty dependencies array to useEffect:

```
React.useEffect(() => {...}, [])
```

That will make it run only on mount.

If you still want to call `fetchConnections` whenever `wallets` changes, you shouldn't do it through an effect hook because you'll get the infinite loop you described. Instead, call `fetchConnections` manually whenever you call `setWallets`. You could make a function that does this for you:

```
const [wallets, setWallets] = useState([]);
const setWalletsAndFetch = (wallets) => {
  setWallets(wallets);
  fetchConnections(wallets);
}
```

Comment: I tried using the 'setWalletsAndFetch' but I got the same results with the same infinite loop, and yes what I'm trying to do is calling fetchConnections whenever wallets changes.

Answer (score 0):

You listen to a change and then as it changes you change it over and over without stopping

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
             fetchConnections();
          })();
       }, []);//remove wallets
```